# Issues with Polymorphic/STI in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

We're having a problem with polymorphism & STI in Ruby

Our database has two tables: 'account' and 'list'.  'list' has columns 'account_id', 'type', 'description'.

Our classes look like so:

```
    class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :lists
      has_many :subscription_lists
      has_many :email_lists
    end

    class List < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :account
    end

    class SubscriptionList < List
    end

    class EmailList < List
    end
```

Inside Account, methods `email_lists` and `subscription_lists` work exactly as expected.  Our goal is we want to be able to call `lists` which will return an array of *all* lists.  Currently, that doesn't work, nor does `self.lists`

Oddly, `Account.find(self.id).lists` DOES give us an array of all the lists associated.

What gives?  How do we fix this?

Comment: So you want `List.all`?? Or do you want `Account.all.map(&:lists)`? I don't see any polymorphism here unless you are custom implementing something.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just a cache issue? What about `self.lists(true)`?

Comment: There's definitely no polymorphic associations in this code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `List.all` which will return an ActiveRecord::Relation of all `List` objects, regardless of type.

Additionally, you can use `@instance_variable.lists` on any instance variable of `Account`

What's more, you could use a query on a class method to accomplish the job, like so, which will also return an ActiveRecord::Relation:

`List.where('account_id = ?', id)`

Lastly, your `Account` association with `List` should not include the children of `List`:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lists, inverse_of: :account, dependent: :destroy
end
```